# Vim netrw explore window focus issue

Tags: vim, netrw

Using vim with no plugins, and an empty .vimrc (so I know nothing is conflicting) I am having a weird problem using the netrw file explorer.

When I work with two vertical split windows, opening a file using `:Explore`, switching to the other window and doing `:Explore` will work as expected, except the focus will switch back to the first window instead of remaining in the explorer view that just opened.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `ctrl+w v` to create a vertical split
2. `:Explore` bring up files and `enter` to open one
3. `ctrl+w w` switch to opposite window
4. `Explore` open explorer
5. Focus returns to the first window

It's driving me nuts - no amount of Googling bears any fruit which makes me wonder if I am using it fundamentally different to every other Vim user!

Tested using Vim 7.3.429 & Vim 7.3.798

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a bug tracker; please contact the plugin's maintainer. Also interesting: which version (have you tried the latest from Dr. Chip's website?) of the netrw plugin do you use?

Comment: Thanks, the latest version from Dr. Chip fixes this. Didn't know about his site before, so double thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Netrw using the latest version from Dr. Chip's website fixes the problem:

http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Comment: While the info on the linked page is retrievable from archive.org, it would be great to at least summarize the indicated "answer" in the body of the answer here.